# Orientation changing padding on activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My app allows orientation change, it also allows for app continuation when orientation is changed by changing the activity line in AndroidManifest to this:

```
<activity android:name="com.cynetstudios.frequencyselector.main" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

**Problem:**

However, starting my app can be done in 2 states:

- **Vertical**

  Application acts normally, default padding, no issue. [Vertical Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te9Ew.jpg), [Change to Horizontal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsTKv.jpg)
- **Horizontal**

  Application has large padding on sides, thus being carried over onto the Vertical layout. [Horizontal Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te9Ew.jpg), [Change to Vertical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te9Ew.jpg)

I have done some research:

It is mentioned to add the `configChange="Orientation"` which I have done, but also to add into my main class:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    this.recreate();
}
```

This does solve the problem but recreates the old issue of the application itself is recreated/relaunched, this any current tasks/threads is killed.

Any suggestions for this padding issue?

Answer (score 1):

create the different layout.xml file for horizontal orientation and tablet

Comment: i was really hoping to avoid this, I might have to, but will wait for any further suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate directory named layout-land and create separate layout's for landscape and keep them inside layout-land directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want same padding on both the sides on both state of orientation then define some padding value to the parent layout. so it will keep the same padding on both the state.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by other users, creating a `layout-land` folder and copying over my activity layout xml file into this new `layout-land` folder helped solving my problem

The cause was due to a `dp` change in my dimens.xml. The horizontal xml defined the horizontal margin of `64pd` while I defined it as `16dp`.

Changing this to `16dp` solved my issue,

also the `onConfigurationChanged()` was not necessary in my case.